# Which Selenium JAR is compatible with Mozilla Firefox version 52 or, latest version

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Previously I was using Selenium version 2.53 with Firefox version 46.1. But now Firefox is updated and I am trying to do with updated version.

So, respond me about "which Selenium JAR is compatible with Mozilla Firefox version 52 or, latest version"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with Selenium 3.4.0 along with latest gecko driver v0.16.0 & Mozila Firefox 53.0, you need to download the gecko driver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and save it. Mention the absolute location of gecko driver in your code as follows:

```
public void sampleMethod() 
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://your_url.com");


}
```

Comment: Can we do without using gecko driver?

Comment: If your Mozilla Firefox have got updated you have to use gecko driver. If you want to avoid using gecko driver, you have to downgrade your Mozilla Firefox to the legacy releases. Next to keep compatibility you have to downgrade your Selenium jar version too which is not recommended :(

Comment: You don't have to downgrade any selenium jars, only your firefox browser must be downgraded to v47.

Comment: @acikojevic Firefox 48.0 or greater does not work with selenium 3.0.0 or greater. You can find more about it here -
 https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/issues/676

Comment: I know, but as I said, after Firefox is downgraded on v47 he doesn't have to downgrade any selenium jars.

Comment: @PrashantKumar great news. Feel free to upvote the Answer if it was useful to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No need to Update the selenium jars since your existing tests may not work properly with new selenium jars. Use the gecko driver to interact with firefox.

Add the path to gecko executable before initiating the Webdriver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
```